# Connecting to Redis host using Lettuce driver and TLS SNI

Tags: ssl, redis, sni, lettuce

I need to connect to Redis with SSL. I have a host and port number but also a servername for TLS SNI. The openssl equivalent is : 
openssl s_client [-connect host:port] [-servername name].

I couldn't find in Lettuce wiki the option for SNI. Can anyone bring some light here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using one of the cloud solutions like RedisLabs? Or set the SSL yourself?

Comment: It's proprietary cloud. Probably won't be using Lettuce - Jedis is simpler, just applies SSLParameters to socket.